# Return output of subprocess.Popen from within a class

Tags: python, oop, subprocess

I'm trying to implement a class for multi-threading and want to use the output to determine what to do next in my program. How can I return the output of self.process as a string? If I try to return the output of self.process.communicate I get an error.

```
#class for multi threading
class Command(object):
    def __init__(self,cmd):
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.process = None

    def run(self,timeout):
        def target():
            print("Thread started")
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            self.process.communicate()                        
            print("Thread finished")            

        thread = threading.Thread(target=target)
        thread.start()

        thread.join(timeout)
        if thread.is_alive():
            print("\nTerminating process")
            self.process.terminate()
            thread.join()            
        print(self.process.returncode) 

def unzip_file(zipped):    
    command = Command(zip_exe+' x '+zipped)
    command.run(timeout = 12000)

unzip_file(zipped)
```

Comment: the subprocess.communicate() returns a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata). That is where the output of the process will be.

Comment: Thanks, how can I access those after "unzip_file" is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually what I do to get the output of my process:

```
class SExec:

def __init__(self, _command):

    _process = Popen(_command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)

    if _process.stderr is None:
        self.stdout = (_process.stdout.read()).decode("utf-8")
        self.return_code = _process.returncode
    else:
        self.stdout = None
        self.stderr = _process.stderr.decode("utf-8")
```

Then, when I want, as an example, to execute something and get it's return, I can do:

```
    dir_info = SExec('ls -lA').stdout
    for _line in dir_info.split('\n'):
        print(_line)
```

I hope my example helps you. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I obviously need to come up to speed with OOP. Anyhow here is the answer that I used...

```
#class for multi threading
class Command(object):
    def __init__(self,cmd):
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.process = None

    def run(self,timeout):
        def target():
            print("Thread started")
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            self.tmp = self.process.stdout.read()
            self.process.communicate()                        
            print("Thread finished")            

        thread = threading.Thread(target=target)
        thread.start()

        thread.join(timeout)
        if thread.is_alive():
            print("\nTerminating process")
            self.process.terminate()
            thread.join()            
        print(self.process.returncode)
```

Then the results can be accessed by accessing self.tmp after using the instance name: command.tmp.